# How to access this government API correctly?

Tags: api

I'm trying to access a US government API found here but am getting a 500 error response:

https://gsa.gov/portal/content/162379

An example listed API endpoint is:

```
https://inventory.data.gov/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b&filters={"FiscalYear":"2017","Zip":"10036"}
```

Here is how I tried to test it with curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"FiscalYear":"2017","County":"Worcester"}' https://inventory.data.gov/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b
```

Am I trying to access it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You are using HTTP POST, you need to issue a **HTTP GET** request.
You can do this by just copying the address as a curl agrument:

```
curl 'https://inventory.data.gov/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b&filters=\{%22FiscalYear%22:%222017%22,%22Zip%22:%2210036%22\}' --compressed
```

Or by using `-G` which'll force curl to use HTTP GET and parse the `-d` argument as a HTTP GET query string (e.g. `?a=1&b=2`) instead of a POST form. (Usually `-d` tells curl to send the argument in a HTTP POST form)

```
curl -G -d resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b -d filters='{"FiscalYear":2017,"Zip":10036}' https://inventory.data.gov/api/action/datastore_search --compressed
```

You can add `--compressed` so that curl will handle compression for you.